# Python class - attribute inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am trying to implement a project using `class inheritance`, where parent class is:

```
class radio:

    def __init__(self, artist=None, track=None, genre=None):

        self.artist = artist 
        self.track = track
        self.genre = genre
```

then I create `methods` for each `attribute` (non working examples):

```
    def seed_artist(self):
        results = api.search(q=self.artist, type='artist')
        return results 

    def seed_track(self):
        results = api.search(q=self.track, type='track')
        return results

    def seed_genre(self):
        results = api.search(q=self.genre, type='genre')
        return results
```

the user is going to pick a seed above (only one), being it either `artist`, `track`, `genre` or `mood`, and that's why I initialize all arguments with `None`, leaving the argument value to be inserted at inheritance level.

the inherited `class` is:

```
class playlist(radio):

    def __init__(self,user):
        radio.__init__(self, artist, track, genre)
```

lets say user inputs at command line a `track seed`, and my script ends up starting with a global variable:

```
track = 'karma police'
```

this way, all other attributes (`artist`, `genre`) remain `None`.

when I create an instance, say:

```
jeff = playlist('Jeff Smith')
```

It will throw an error saying that `genre` and `artist` are not defined, and I would have to inherit only `track`attribute, like so:

```
radio.__init__(self, track)
```

I know I could start the script with global variables defined:

```
track = None
genre = None
artist = None
```

and this would allow me to have:

```
radio.__init__(self, artist, track, genre)
```

but this seems to me rather redundant...

Is there a workaround this, with no need for initial values of global variables set to `None`, keeping all the code within class scope definitions?

Comment: I gave an answer below, but it's hard to say what the alternative for the global variables is, because you haven't shown or even described how your code gets from user input to creating a global variable called `tracks`.  One possibility is to make `playlist` also accept `track`, `artist`, etc., and have your input-parsing code pass a dict to it in a manner similar to what I described in my answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn I've edited the question for you, in case you might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate global variable for each field, use a single dictionary for all fields.  Then you can pass the dictionary as keyword arguments.

That is, instead of creating a global variable called `artist`, create a dictionary called `radio_fields` or something.  When the user inputs their query, set a key on this dict:

```
radio_fields = {}
...
# when you get the user's command
radio_fields['track'] = 'Karma Police'
```

Now you can call `radio.__init__(self, **radio_fields)`.  This will pass as arguments whatever keys are in `radio_fields`.  If there is only one, only that one will be passed, and the others will take their default values as you defined them when you defined `radio.__init__`.

There might be a better way to structure your overall program, but it's hard to say based on what you've shown here.  For instance, it's unclear why `playlist` only accepts one `user` argument.  If `playlist` accepted all the field arguments that `radio` accepted, it could pass them on to `radio` without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have those variables to pass, so don't try and pass them. The parent class already has defaults for them, so just pass the one you need:

```
radio.__init__(self, artist=artist)
```

Comment: The problem is then he would have to write a bunch of separate calls depending on which variables are defined, along with a tangle of `if` statements to decide which call to use.

Comment: but I don't know the one I need... That's the user's call.